# Adding triple containing blank node to Stardog with RDFLib

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, stardog, blank-nodes

I'm using the RDFLib Python library to manipulate a Stardog database. How do I add a blank node? I'm trying `g.add((BNode(),FOAF.knows,Literal('amy')))`, but I get an exception "SPARQLStore does not support Bnodes!". What is the alternative?

Comment: But one alternative to try could be using a SPARQL INSERT directly, which might be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a restriction of RDFLib's SPARQLStore implementation, which you seem to be using. See the [docs](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/2.4.0/apidocs/rdflib.plugins.stores.html?highlight=sparqlstore#rdflib.plugins.stores.sparqlstore.SPARQLStore).

You may be able to accomplish this by using [SPARQLWrapper](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/) to insert the triples directly without using the RDFLib interface.

Comment: You could also drop down to using the Stardog command line: http://docs.stardog.com/#_man_pages